# Cite after end of sentence mangles whitespace

Tags: spacing, citing

I am using the report class to write a thesis. Sometimes, more than one consecutive sentences refer to the same source, so instead of writing `Booh \cite{source}. Baah \cite{source}.` I write `Booh. Baah. \cite{source}`. But then, the citation reference is trailed by an enlarged space (indicating the end of a sentence) and followed by a normal one.

This way, the reader associates the citation reference to the following sentence, not the one it is standing behind.

I can suppress the enlarged space with `\<space>`. But how do I get the enlarged space after the citation?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
Hello, I am a sentence \cite{testcitation}. I am 
a sentence as well. \cite{testcitation} And me too!
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Test output.]

Comment: Have you tried inserting `\phantom{.}` after the second `cite` instruction?

Comment: Didn't know that command yet, thank you. :-) Unfortunately, this produces a too large space as it puts in an invisible dot as well.

Comment: +1 for a question particularly well asked by a relatively new visitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm under the impression that your readers won't understand what the citation after the period refers to. This said, here's how you can do:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\cite}{\leavevmode\spacefactor@remember}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\@citex}{\spacefactor@reset}{}{}
\newcommand{\spacefactor@remember}{%
  \ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip~\fi
  \xdef\spacefactor@value{\the\spacefactor}%
  \spacefactor\@m
}
\newcommand{\spacefactor@reset}{\spacefactor=\spacefactor@value\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\xspaceskip=20pt % just to show the extended spaces more clearly

Hello, I am a sentence \cite{testcitation}. I am 
a sentence as well. \cite{testcitation} And me too!

\end{document}
```

The setting to `\xspaceskip` is just to mark more clearly the end-of-sentence spaces.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is just awesome, and I do not understand a single word between ...letter and ...other! ;) 
Unfortunately, this only works as long as I do not use biblatex -- as soon as I add the line `\usepackage[backend=bibtex, urldate=comp, style=numeric-comp, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}`, it stops working. So biblatex plays around with the cite command, right? :-(

Comment: @hepfi That was fundamental information: with `biblatex` different workarounds are needed, because it does change `\cite`.

Comment: I am very sorry about this, I forgot to mention it when stripping down the example to be as minimal as possible. :-( Would it be easier if I just built myself a wrapper command around `\cite`?

Comment: @hepfi Sorry, but you should make a complete new question, stating precisely what bibliographic package you use and also what citation commands you're going to use and that should be affected by the behavior.

Comment: Okay, then I will do that and since your code works just remove anything biblatex-related from THIS question and accept your answer.