# Cite after end of sentence mangles whitespace (Biblatex!)

Tags: spacing, biblatex, citing

(This is an almost-duplicate of [Cite after end of sentence mangles whitespace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267060/cite-after-end-of-sentence-mangles-whitespace), since I forgot to mention Biblatex there.)

I am using the report class to write a thesis. Sometimes, more than one consecutive sentences refer to the same source, so instead of writing `Booh \cite{source}. Baah \cite{source}.` I write `Booh. Baah. \cite{source}`. But then, the citation reference is trailed by an enlarged space (indicating the end of a sentence) and followed by a normal one.

This way, the reader associates the citation reference to the following sentence, not the one it is standing behind.

I can suppress the enlarged space with `\<space>`. But how do I get the enlarged space after the citation?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, urldate=comp, style=numeric-comp, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test.bib} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{urldate}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}

\begin{document}

\xspaceskip=20pt % just to show the extended spaces more clearly

Hello, I am a sentence \cite{testarticle}. I am 
a sentence as well. \cite{testarticle} And me too!

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Test.bib:

```
@ARTICLE{testarticle,
  author = {Fowl, Artemis},
  title = {How many centaurs fit into a chair?},
  journal = {LEPRecon Journal},
  year = {2016},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {429--439},
  number = {64}
}
```

Output (the setting to `\xspaceskip` is just to mark more clearly the end-of-sentence spaces):

[image: Sample output.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this spacing seems completely wrong to me (`[1]` is not a sentence) but it may be produced by the following which inserts the space factor of `.` without typesetting a `.`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, urldate=comp, style=numeric-comp, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test2.bib} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{urldate}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}

\begin{document}

\xspaceskip=20pt % just to show the extended spaces more clearly

Hello, I am a sentence \cite{testarticle}.
a sentence as well. \cite{testarticle}\spacefactor\sfcode`\.{}
 And me too!

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you cery much -- this works very well. With that, I can define `\newcommand{\zitat}[1]{\cite{#1}}` for the normal ones and `\newcommand{\pzitat}[1]{\ \zitat{#1}\spacefactor\sfcode\`\.{}}` for the ones after dots.